# django. Добавить ссылку на приложение в админке

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Я использую django-jet тему для админки django.

В админке django  слева есть сайд бар, где отображается список приложений. Мне хотелось бы добавить туда ссылку на страницу, которая не зависит от модели, но имела бы тот же интерфейс, что амдинка. Не совсем понятно как добавить эту ссылку. Без модели и вовсе моё приложение там не отображается.

Из гугла понял, что нужно переопределить шаблон, который отвечает за список приложений и руками туда прописать ссылку, но это кажется костыльным решением и не совсем понятно от какого шаблона наследоваться.

Ниже прикрепил скрин.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В документации всё есть https://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html#custom-menu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить урл как говорится в документации, через [JET_SIDE_MENU_ITEMS](http://jet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/config_file.html#custom-menu).

Пример из документации:

```
JET_SIDE_MENU_ITEMS = [  # A list of application or custom item dicts
    {'label': _('General'), 'app_label': 'core', 'items': [
        {'name': 'help.question'},
        {'name': 'pages.page', 'label': _('Static page')},
        {'name': 'city'},
        {'name': 'validationcode'},
        {'label': _('Analytics'), 'url': 'http://example.com', 'url_blank': True},
    ]},
    {'label': _('Users'), 'items': [
        {'name': 'core.user'},
        {'name': 'auth.group'},
        {'name': 'core.userprofile', 'permissions': ['core.user']},
    ]},
    {'app_label': 'banners', 'items': [
        {'name': 'banner'},
        {'name': 'bannertype'},
    ]},
]
```